# Lua damage meter percent

Tags: lua

I am in the process of making a combat table in Lua and I am very new to Lua. The output should looks like this:

Results of the last combat:

```
Damage Done:    
1 >>>> Alice 200 (CRITICAL) 
2 Bob 60    
3 Alice 30  
4 Alice 30  
5 >>>> Alice 45 (CRITICAL)  
6 >>>> Bob 120 (CRITICAL)   
7 Bob 300   
8 Alice 100 
9 Bob 50
```

Percent Total Damage Done:

```
1 Bob 57%   
1 Heavy Attack (1) 57%  
2 Lava Whip (2) 34% 
3 Light Attack (1) 9%   
2 Alice 43% 
1 Crystal Shard (2) 74% 
2 Lightning Splash (3) 26%
```

Your Damage Stats:

```
Average: 81
Min: 30
Max: 200
```

Healing Done:

```
1 >>>> Carol 400 (CRITICAL) 
2 Carol 200 
3 Alice 200
```

**Percent Total Healing Done:**

```
1 Carol 75% 
1 Regeneration (2) 100% 
2 Alice 25% 
1 Regeneration (1) 100%
```

Your Healing Stats:

```
Average: 200
Min: 200
Max: 200
```

I have already coded in the critical part and now I am stuck on figuring out how to calculate the percentage of the total damage done. any help would be appreciated. Here is a chunk of code:

```
function CombatReport:OnEndCombat(combatEndTime)
combatDurationTime = combatEndTime - self.combatStartTime + 1
print("*****************************************")
print("** Combat Report".." ("..combatDurationTime.." seconds)")
print("*****************************************")
print("Results of the last combat:\n")

damageEvents = "Damage Done:\n"
count = 1
for i = 1, self.numCombatEvents do
    damage = self.combatEvents[i][3]
    sourceName = self.combatEvents[i][1]
    isCrit = self.combatEvents[i][5]


    if damage > 0 then
        damageEvents = damageEvents .. "#"
        damageEvents = damageEvents .. count
        if isCrit then
          damageEvents = damageEvents .. " >>>>"
        end
        damageEvents = damageEvents .. " "
        damageEvents = damageEvents .. sourceName
        damageEvents = damageEvents .. " "
        damageEvents = damageEvents .. damage
        if isCrit then
          damageEvents = damageEvents .. " (CRITICAL)"
        end
        damageEvents = damageEvents .. "\n"
        count = count + 1
    end
end


print(damageEvents)
```

This is the part I edited to add in the crit.

Here are my combat events:

```
local COMBAT_EVENTS =
{
{ "Alice",      "Molag Bal",    200,    0,      true,   1,  "Crystal Shard"         },
{ "Bob",        "Molag Bal",    60,     0,      false,  2,  "Lava Whip" },
{ "Alice",      "Molag Bal",    30,     0,      false,  3,  "Lightning Splash" },
{ "Carol",      "Alice",        0,      400,    true,   4,  "Regeneration" },
{ "Alice",      "Molag Bal",    30,     0,      false,  5,  "Lightning Splash" },
{ "Alice",      "Molag Bal",    45,     0,      true,   6,  "Lightning Splash" },
{ "Bob",        "Molag Bal",    120,    0,      true,   7,  "Lava Whip" },
{ "Bob",        "Molag Bal",    300,    0,      false,  8,  "Heavy Attack" },
{ "Carol",      "Bob",          0,      200,    false,  9,  "Regeneration" },
{ "Alice",      "Molag Bal",    100,    0,      false,  10, "Crystal Shard" },
{ "Bob",        "Molag Bal",    50,     0,      false,  11, "Light Attack" },
{ "Alice",      "Alice",        0,      200,    false,  12, "Regeneration" }
}
```

Comment: don't you know how to calculate that percentage value or how to implement that in Lua? did you try anything?

Comment: I'm just happy that as a newbie to Lua you don't call it LUA. Props for research.

Comment: Get the sum of each damage type for each player and divide that by the player's total damage.

Comment: Thankyou Hromgo I will give this a shot. Like I said I am new to Lua and I am not familiar with the syntax and I am mostly having trouble with being able to create a running total of all the players damage. If I new how to do that this would be much easier.